# Finding value based on date and name on same row

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been doing lots of if/else with sheets, and little of all kind, but now i'm facing a problem with not so familiar formula.

So let's use pseudo-coding if it helps: if (A1=A2 and B1=B2) = in same row; return value -1 offset of A2

So i have a:

-schedule with columns(Date, WorkID, WorkerID, WorkID, WorkerID, WorkID....)

-list with columns(Date, and where i need WorkID to be placed)
So i need to get the matching date and the WorkID only if WorkerID matches.

I can do that with one column without WorkID, but it needs to be filtered with WorkerID somehow: =index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H12;vuorot!A:A;0);8)

If i could get that, then i could maybe use if/and etc. to combine results from all WorkID+WorkerID-columns.

I tried to look about index, match, offset, query, lookup... So many options that i'm lost.

EDIT: I hate this... Searching for long time for how to do it, then after posting a question, then finally figured it out, atleast partly, and i found out also that you can leave "else" from "if" if you want blank result:

=IF(index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);9)=$D$2;index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);8);) The $D$2 is WorkerID

And it created this monster: =IF(index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);3)=$D$2;index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);2);IF(index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);5)=$D$2;index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);4);IF(index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);7)=$D$2;index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);6);IF(index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);9)=$D$2;index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);8);IF(index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);10)=$D$2;index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);11);IF(index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);13)=$D$2;index(vuorot!A:M;MATCH(H11;vuorot!A:A;0);12);))))))

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Welcome! If this monster looks so scary, then there must be an easier way. It is a pity that the question does not have an image of the data or a link to an example table (from the verbal description it is difficult to understand how the data is located). But perhaps [**this question**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-value-from-a-rectangular-table/1029?u=johnsun) will give you an idea.

Comment: Keep in mind that we cannot see your spreadsheet. We don't know your sheet setup, layout, data, data types or end goal. We don't know the scope of your business or field. So while your post likely makes complete sense to you (who *can* see everything and who *does* know your end goal and field), for us "out here," it would be all but impossible to understand your post. As JohnSUN suggests, please share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), so that we can see what you are seeing.